# Liquibase sql is successful but cant see actual tables in postgres db hosted in docker

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, liquibase

I am facing an issue with liquibase + springboot +postgres + docker integration.
I have hosted database in docker image

[image]

Here is **pom.xml** entry

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.11.0</liquibase.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/moviesdb
    username: movies_dbo
    password: movies@123
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      generate-ddl: true
      show-sql: true

  server:
    port: 9093

  liquibase:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/moviesdb
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    user: movies_dbo
    password: movies@41
    changeLog: "classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml"
    contexts: dev
    dropFirst: false
    liquibaseSchemaName: moviesdb
```

**db.changelog-master.yaml**

databaseChangeLog:

```
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/movies_db_package.sql
      context: dev
```

**movies_db_package.sql**

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset abbhiinav:create-movies-table-1 splitStatements:true endDelimiter: failOnError:true;
--rollback DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xyz_movie;


CREATE TABLE xyz_movie
(
    movie_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration     TIMESTAMP,
    title        VARCHAR(256),
    description  VARCHAR(512),
    language     VARCHAR(20),
    release_date TIMESTAMP,
    country      VARCHAR(100),
    genre        VARCHAR(20)
);
```

After these when I run my application, everything seems running fine and even I can see liquibase executing the script and inserting the entry in public.databasechangelog

```
11:53:00.103 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
11:53:00.103 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
11:53:00.184 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
11:53:00.469 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
11:53:00.655 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
11:53:00.890 [main] INFO  liquibase.database - Set default schema name to public
11:53:01.137 [main] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully acquired change log lock
11:53:01.220 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Creating database history table with name: public.databasechangelog
11:53:01.240 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from public.databasechangelog
Running Changeset: db/changelog/movies_db_package.sql::create-movies-table-2::abbhiinav
11:53:01.402 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Custom SQL executed
11:53:01.406 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog - ChangeSet db/changelog/movies_db_package.sql::create-movies-table-2::abbhiinav ran successfully in 38ms
11:53:01.460 [main] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully released change log lock
11:53:01.660 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
11:53:01.739 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
11:53:01.897 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
11:53:02.020 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
11:53:02.654 [main] INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
11:53:03.442 [main] INFO  s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
11:53:03.828 [main] INFO  s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Context refreshed
11:53:03.863 [main] INFO  s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
11:53:03.894 [main] INFO  s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner - Scanning for api listing references
11:53:04.082 [main] INFO  c.x.m.MovieserviceApplication - Started MovieserviceApplication in 6.732 seconds (JVM running for 7.167)
```

Then I tried checking the postgres db again abut coudnt see any tables created

[image]

I have also tried it via pgadmin but I can't see the table there as well.

If I re-run my application by changing the version in movies_db_package.sql
like
--changeset abs:create-movies-table-**3** splitStatements:true endDelimiter: failOnError:true;

I get an error that table/relation already exists, re-run log specified below

```
11:54:49.909 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
11:54:49.947 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/movies_db_package.sql::create-movies-table-3::abbhiinav:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "xyz_movie" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE xyz_movie
(
    movie_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration     TIMESTAMP,
    title        VARCHAR(256),
    description  VARCHAR(512),
    language     VARCHAR(20),
    release_date TIMESTAMP,
    country      VARCHAR(100),
    genre        VARCHAR(20)
)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.xyz.movieservice.MovieserviceApplication.main(MovieserviceApplication.java:12)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/movies_db_package.sql::create-movies-table-3::abbhiinav:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "xyz_movie" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE xyz_movie
(
    movie_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration     TIMESTAMP,
    title        VARCHAR(256),
    description  VARCHAR(512),
    language     VARCHAR(20),
    release_date TIMESTAMP,
    country      VARCHAR(100),
    genre        VARCHAR(20)
)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:126)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$null$0(Liquibase.java:265)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:264)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2405)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:211)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:197)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/movies_db_package.sql::create-movies-table-3::abbhiinav:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "xyz_movie" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE xyz_movie
(
    movie_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration     TIMESTAMP,
    title        VARCHAR(256),
    description  VARCHAR(512),
    language     VARCHAR(20),
    release_date TIMESTAMP,
    country      VARCHAR(100),
    genre        VARCHAR(20)
)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:696)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:56)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$null$0(ChangeLogIterator.java:113)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$run$1(ChangeLogIterator.java:112)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:93)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:247)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:65)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "xyz_movie" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE xyz_movie
(
    movie_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    duration     TIMESTAMP,
    title        VARCHAR(256),
    description  VARCHAR(512),
    language     VARCHAR(20),
    release_date TIMESTAMP,
    country      VARCHAR(100),
    genre        VARCHAR(20)
)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:397)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:83)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:151)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1279)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1261)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:661)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "xyz_movie" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:393)
    ... 61 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am really puzzelled about if tables is not created in actual db then how come it is failing on re-run stating that relation already exists,I have wasted few days in it ,I really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: let me know if more info is required, I have to cut down more details due to character limit in question

Comment: That is a lot of information - Thanks for being so thorough. Could you edit and rewrite so the question is at the top, maybe to be more like a User Story? I facilitate getting answers from the Liquibase team to the community, and I'm not 100% clear about what you're asking.  A user story follows this format: As a (DBA, Liquibase user, Java Programmer, IT manager, etc - your persona as the requestor) want to (stop X from failing when I do this thing) so that (I can view the table after running the process). Give a clear picture of who you are, what you want to happen, and why you want it.